# intersphinx link to pandas autodoc API

Tags: python, pandas, python-sphinx, autodoc

I'm attempting to link to the `apply()` autodoc documentation at: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html.

I can link to the release page at: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/release.html by using...

```
:ref:`release <pandas:release>`
```

... but I can't seem to get the proper link to the autodoc pages. My intersphinx mapping is configured as...

```
{'python': ('http://docs.python.org/', None),
 'pandas': ('http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev', None)}`
```

... and I've tried the following variations of links to the `apply()` method:

```
:ref:`apply <pandas:pandas.dataframe.apply>`
:ref:`apply <pandas:pandas-dataframe-apply>`
:ref:`apply <pandas:dataframe.apply>`
:ref:`apply <pandas:DataFrame.apply>`
:ref:`apply <pandas.DataFrame.apply>`
:ref:`apply <pandas.dataframe.apply>`
:meth:`apply <pandas:pandas.dataframe.apply>`
:meth:`pandas:pandas.dataframe.apply`
:meth:`pandas.dataframe.apply`
```

## Answer

As mzjn answered below, the link is case sensitive so any of the following work in my situation:

```
:meth:`apply <pandas:pandas.DataFrame.apply>`
:meth:`pandas:pandas.DataFrame.apply`
:meth:`pandas.DataFrame.apply`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be careful with the spelling. All the cross-references in the question that use the `:meth:` role will work if `dataframe` is changed to `DataFrame`.